# How to recover a corrupted sd card

Tags: camera, recovery, corrupt

Is there a free, fast way to recover the contents of an sd card? I have an sd card that originally belonged to a camera, with videos and photos on it. Recently, the camera no longer can take pictures, and the sd card looks like this on a computer.

The files and folders are replaced with random symbols, and are impossible to open.

[image]

I've tried multiple computers, and a software that didn't let me recover the images without paying. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Pls. remove your post, it isn't about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming

Comment: Questions about general software and hardware are explicitly off-topic for this site unless they're about programming tools.

Comment: [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a data ripper - it looks up file magic bytes, and copies the whole files into separate location. If your camera has corrupted the SD card when plugged out and in, I suppose you'll be able to recover min. 70% of data, but don't assume this, as it is computing black magic. There are many free data rippers.

Anyways, this question belongs to your camera or SD card vendor's support tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Piriform Recuva is a free option:
https://www.piriform.com/recuva

The following was copied from the Piriform website Recuva documentation at the time of this writing ([source](http://www.piriform.com/docs/recuva/introducing-recuva/what-it-can-and-cant-do)):

**What it can and cant do**

**Recuva can:**

1. Scan through your hard drives, memory cards, and USB sticks to find files and folders you've deleted.
2. Tell you in advance how likely it is that your file(s) can be recovered.
3. Recover files that Windows can't (see Problems with Windows and file deletion)
4. Securely delete a file you may have previously deleted.
5. Recover emails you deleted 'permanently' from Microsoft Outlook Express, Mozilla Thunderbird, or Windows Live Mail.
6. Recover files from your iPod, iPod Nano, or iPod Shuffle (iPod Touch and iPhone not supported at this time). Recuva will even recover songs with Apple's FairPlay DRM.
7. Recover Canon RAW (.CRW) format image files.
8. Recover files from NTFS, FAT, and exFAT-formatted drives.
9. Bring your files back!

**Recuva cannot:**

1. Recover all files. Yes, as great as Recuva is it won't work all the time. Sometimes Windows has overwritten the area where the file used to be, or sometimes the file is too corrupted to recover.
2. Recover files you've deleted securely. For example, if you've used our CCleaner software to delete files using the Secure option, they're gone for good.
3. Securely delete certain very small files that are held in the Master File Table (MFT) and files of zero-byte length.
4. Recuva is capable of recovering from NAS devices, however the drive needs to be connected directly to the machine via USB/IDE/SATA. Recuva is not capable of recovering data over a network.

Comment: Thanks Petter. I updated the answer with some context